# Hosting Multiple websites on apache2?

Tags: redirect, apache2, directory, virtualhost

I'm using Ubuntu Server with Apache2 to host my websites.

I have two domains, www.test.com and www.domain.com (not real names)

Inside of my sites-available I have the default that is pointed to my www.test.com domain and then I have a created one for www.domain.com inside that I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domainfolder
<Directory />
Options +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the website works, I can navigate to it and use it but since I'm using it for wordpress when ever I click on say Admin CP it will try to navigate to www.domain.com/domainfolder/admin-cp/ I'm just not sure why it's trying to access the folder it's stored in?

Using .htaccess just gives me an internal server error because it's always going down a directory, here is the code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domainfolder/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

They would need separate addresses in Virtual hosts to use separate directories.

Given example.com and folders one, two, and three

You need to choose 
1. example.com (one), example.com/two and example.com/three
or example.com (one), two.example.com and three.example.com

1. example.com (one), two.com and three.com

Given 
DocumentRoot /www/subdomain/sub1
ServerName www.sub1.domain.tld
ServerPath /sub1/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/sub1/.*) /www/subdomain$1
```

Do you have a rule similar to the highlighted section above, rewrites are how you get the pretty address you are looking for.

Also, make sure apache mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: I'm not on about the subdomain? My default site along with its two subdomains work fine, it's my second domain that is the problem.